# Salesforce Change Data Capture with Cross-ORG external object

Tags: lightning-connect, change-data-capture

I am facing an issue with Change Data Capture

1. I enabled the Change Data Capture (CDC) feature on Opportunity in the source ORG.
2. I am able to write a trigger on the OpportunityChangeEvent in source ORG.
3. Now, I created a cross-org external data source connection in a different ORG to the source ORG.
4. I validated and synced the Opportunity Object from the Source Org. So, Opportunity__x is the external Object in my destination ORG.
5. Now, I want to capture the changes on Opportunity (from source ORG) in the destination ORG.
6. I tried creating a trigger on the Opportunity_ChangeEvent (on external object) in the destination ORG. But its failing.

How could I capture the change events on external Opportunity in the destination ORG? Is this supported in Salesforce? I see this is supported for OData 2.0/4.0 connections. But I don't see for the Cross-Org connections. If not supported, are there any other options to do this?

Please help me on this.

Comment: You need [Salesforce Connect + cross-org adapter](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning_connect/lightning_connect_introduction) to surface SF objects from one org in another org. If you have all of that, you don't need CDC. Take a look at [Integration Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm) for more info

Comment: @identigral, I have that cross-org salesforce connect connection and I was able to visualize the data in the destination ORG. But I need to write a trigger on that external object for some internal processing. how can I do that?

Comment: Right, now we see where you're going. You can't do a trigger on an external object but you can do a trigger on an External CDC event in the destination org. External CDC is almost but not quite identical to plain CDC, you might be missing a toggle of this feature on the data source. Double-check your setup versus [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_change_tracking_intro.htm&type=5) + the Codey example in there

Comment: @identigral, the codey example is with Odata 4.0 but not with Cross-Org. There is no example for Triggers on External Objects for Cross-Org connections in that resource. And I also see 'Eligible for External Change Data Capture', 'Track Data Changes' only in the case of Odata 4.0 but not cross-org type in the data source.

Comment: _From the External Objects list , select the external object that you want to track.
Click Edit, and select Track Data Changes_ . This is cross-org, the external object is from a foreign org.

Comment: @speruri any word on this?  I have the exact same need, and am shocked that the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_change_tracking_intro.htm&type=5) (and experience) seems to suggest that out-of-box CDC is available for OData 4.0 adapters but NOT the Cross-Org adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (Winter '21) Change Data Capture still isn't supported for Cross-Org (or custom Apex) adapters--only OData 4.0 according to [this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_change_tracking_intro.htm&type=5).

According to [this June '19 recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhUrjvhFtao&t=27m31s) from Salesforce, adding support for External CDC with Cross-Org adapters is on the "longer term" roadmap.